# Getting integers from file into an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program where the user enters the name of a file containing test scores, and the test scores are stored into an array and different functions are performed. I am having trouble getting the text file to be read into an array. I keep getting a ton of errors when I try to run the program. Here is the code I am trying to use. I am a beginner by the way.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class TestScores {

  public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException 
  {
    int number=1;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter filename");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    File inputFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner filesource = new Scanner(new FileReader(inputFile));

    System.out.print(inputFile);

    int intarray[] = new int[99];
    for (int j=0; j<number; j++) {
      if (filesource.hasNext()) {
        intarray[j] = filesource.nextInt();
        number++;
        System.out.println(intarray[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried using a while loop but that didn't work either. I am also wondering how do I initialize an array if I don't know how many elements there will be?

I am getting the following errors

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at TestScores.main(TestScores.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at ....model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

*Edit*: The file consists of the numbers 13 98 78 86 45 66 92 97 82 51 70 90 80 86 where 13 is the number of data entries in the set. (from OPs comments).

Comment: can you post up your file content plz?

Comment: <offtopic> `int intarray[] = new int[99];`, potential overflow. Use `List<Integer>` instead.

Comment: what kind of error do you get? it works in my pc

Comment: When I enter the file I get errors. The file consists of the numbers 13 98 78 86 45 66 92 97 82 51 70 90 80 86
where 13 is the number of data entries in the set

Comment: could you post up the error? my guess is you have issue with relative and absolute path

Comment: while this doesn't sound like the cause of your error your loop goes to `number` instead of the size of the array `99`. Also you can combine the `for` and `if` into a cleaner `while((number < 99) && (filesource.hasNext()))`

Comment: I'd like to point out that its looks like you need to consider the first number of the series as the number of elements, which I did not find in you code. I gave you an answer anyway: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/24602191/1461424].

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class TestScores 
{

public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException 
{

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter filename");
String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

String Line = null;
ArrayList<Integer> ContentList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(filename);
BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

while ((Line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   
{
    ContentList.add(Line+ "\n");
}

bufferReader.close();

int intarray[] = new int[99];  //Better to use array list here also
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ContentList.size(); i++)
{
    int intarray[j++] = Integer.parseInt(ContentList.get(i).split(" +"));
//enters each element(integer) in the file to intarray
    System.out.println(intarray[j]);
}
}
```

Its not a good practice to throw IOException from the main method.
Instead create another class which has the same code and call it from main method. Ask this class to throw IOException.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(ContentList.get(i).split(" +"));` Really? What does it even do?

Comment: "Integer.parseInt" converts a string into an Integer. But, if the string does not contain integers it gives a run time exception.

"ContentList" is an ArrayList and ".get" gets the value of each index using "i".

".split" splits the string into an array based on the parameter given i.e (" +") which means one or more spaces.

The return value of the whole statement is Integer Array and so have initialized to "intarray"

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle's Java docs, [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

> `hasNext()` Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.
>
> `hasNextInt()`  Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the `nextInt()` method.

(This is a wild guess since you don't have your file uploaded). Your file may have a token that can be read, but it may not necessarily be readable as `int`. Try using `hasNextInt()`.

PS: Also, the use of both `for` and `if` is unnecessary. You can structure the code like this:

```
int index = 0;
while (filsource.hasNextInt()) {
    intarray[index++] = filesource.nextInt();
    // anything else you want to do
}

number = index + 1; // number of ints read
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does actually work, as Santosh Pavate said there are some good practices you should adopt.

However, as I said it works, IF and only IF you have your file formatted correctly, I tried with the following configurations:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Just as some simple tests, and it did work, however when I tried something like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

That's when I got the same error as you. The error is because you are calling "nextInt()" on your Scanner and the next character(s) are not valid integer ones. To fix this you just need to make sure you file is formatted correctly, or IF you have something like my example where it failed, the answers being separated by commas, you can try altering the delimiter on your scanner with userDelimiter(String) or useDelimiter(Pattern).

*-Thomas*

Comment: _you just need to make sure you file is formatted correctly_ And you can enforce this by using `hasNextInt()` in place of `hasNext()`. See my answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/24602191/1461424]

Comment: The file is formatted like the second one (1 2 3 4 5) but I am still getting errors anyway